# Call shell script set env when Vim startup

Tags: vim, environment-variables

I'm calling the following function on `VimEnter`

```
autocmd VimEnter * call InitVimProject()

function! InitVimProject()
    let initFile = "./viminit.sh"
    if filereadable(initFile)
        silent exec '!source ' . initFile
        redraw!
    endif
endfunction
```

And then I want to set env variable when I startup Vim on a different project

Like set a golang `$GOPATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash

CURDIR=`pwd`
GOPATH=$CURDIR":$CURDIR/utility"
echo $GOPATH
```

But when I startup Vim, I try `:!echo $GOPATH`, It's not changed

I confirmed this script is executing.

How can I solve this problem, Or are there any other ways?

Comment: Why don't you source directly? Like :au VimEnter * :source Filename

Comment: `:!surce ./viminit.sh` happens in a subshell so it has no effect on the current session. Also, the only environment variables seen by Vim (or any other CLI program) are the ones set *before* starting it.

Comment: @SibiCoder I try it, But had same problem

Comment: @romainl Ok, Thanks u